# Saving path when Importing Data using MATLAB's default GUI

Tags: matlab, file-io

My MATLAB scripts live in the Matlab installation dir, while my data files live on other HDDs. When I run my scripts and import data via `uigetfile`, I save the path to the most recently imported data (in an "ini" file), and default to that path upon the next `uigetfile` call. This allows me to navigate to the most recent data quicker, and this is what (essentially) all software I know does (like opening documents from a recent location in Office).

However, when I need to import data using the MATLAB GUI (not via my own scripts), MATLAB always defaults to the MATLAB start path, and never saves the most recent path the data was imported from. In the long run, this makes importing data from the MATLAB GUI tedious. Is there a way to make MATLAB's GUI save the most recent path to data that it imported from? This would be like Office always defaulting to the location to its bin folder when trying to open a document; every MATLAB version I dealt with (since about 2001) had this.

[image: Screenshot of MATLAB's GUI: Import Data]

Answer (score 0):

The `importdata` GUI button selects the current folder as the default location, so you can change that and it will select a different folder, e.g.

`cd C:\Temp\DataFolder`

Then when you click on import folder it will use that folder as the default location.

Comment: Matlabgui -- thank you for the response. This was my first thought, too, but it involves extra clicks (and advanced thinking each time I navigate between different data folders). I was hoping I could tweak the ML default behavior.

Comment: I suspect you can use `uigetfile`, pick the files your self and pass the file into `importdata` function

Comment: Then to get the functionality I need I would have to modify uigetfile to load startdir from my own ini file, and save it again after I loaded the file. uigetfil.m appears to be mcc-precompiled. Or write a script and run it every time I need to import data from the ML GUI. I guess that would work.

Comment: You can pass a directory/default file into `uigetfile` as an input.  Maybe if you shared more of your code/workflow it would be easier to provide guidance

Comment: matlabgui -- I was not talking about my own code; I can do whatever with my own code. I was talking about default matlab behavior in its own gui (and showed a screenshot if the respective button)